# Mysql Count with Custom Limit

Tags: mysql

I'm making some report, my data look like this :

```
text    date                    text    date
a       18/01/2016 12:01        a       18/01/2016 13:01
b       18/01/2016 12:01        b       18/01/2016 13:01
c       18/01/2016 12:01        c       18/01/2016 13:01
d       18/01/2016 12:01        x       18/01/2016 13:01
e       18/01/2016 12:01        y       18/01/2016 13:01
f       18/01/2016 12:01        z       18/01/2016 13:01
g       18/01/2016 12:01        g       18/01/2016 13:01
h       18/01/2016 12:01        h       18/01/2016 13:01
i       18/01/2016 12:01        i       18/01/2016 13:01
```

To get the total number of text :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total FROM table 
WHERE DAY(date) = DAY('2016-01-18') 
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH('2016-01-18') 
AND YEAR(date) = YEAR('2016-01-18') 
GROUP BY text ORDER BY total DESC
```

Result :

```
a   2
b   2
c   2
d   1
e   1
f   1
g   1
h   1
i   1
x   1
y   1
z   1
```

My problem is, i only want to use top 5 data every hour, and want a result like this :

```
data : 
a       18/01/2016 12:01        a       18/01/2016 13:01
b       18/01/2016 12:01        b       18/01/2016 13:01
c       18/01/2016 12:01        c       18/01/2016 13:01
d       18/01/2016 12:01        x       18/01/2016 13:01
e       18/01/2016 12:01        y       18/01/2016 13:01

result :
a   2
b   2
c   2
d   1
e   1
x   1
y   1
```

Comment: Try "limit 5" at the end of your query.

Comment: in expected result there are 7 records ?

Comment: @Aravind i mean, a b c d e (5 top row at 18/01/2016 12:01) + a b c x y (5 top row at 18/01/2016 13:01)  so total sliced from two data is a = 2, b = 2, c = 2, d = 1, e = 1, x = 1, z = 1

Comment: Have you tried "ORDER BY total,date DESC LIMIT 5" ?

Comment: @Aravind limit 5 will show : g = 2, h = 2, i = 2, a = 2, b = 2. i expected a = 2, b = 2, c = 2, d = 1, e = 1, x = 1, y = 1

Comment: @Adrian Yoan you must add `text ASC` to order by.

Comment: @mhasan yes, i expected 7 record a, b, c, d, e, x, y

Comment: @Adrian Yoan you mean you need to get `limit 5` of 'each' record?

Comment: May be you should query twice separately. Then add the result or throw it to temp table and count it again.

Comment: @FrozenFire yes, first limit 5 per-day next count total ;)

Comment: @Adrian Yoan in your sample above you're doing it per hour not per day.

Comment: @FrozenFire sorry, i mean per hour :)

Comment: @Adrian Yoan I think you need to get the `distinct date` first, then run the query with limit 5, throw it to temp table, before counting it.

Answer (score 0):

The query shown below will give the result required,

```
SELECT text, max(date) as maxdate, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM table 
WHERE 
DAY(date) = DAY('2016-01-18') 
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH('2016-01-18') 
AND YEAR(date) = YEAR('2016-01-18') 
GROUP BY text ORDER BY maxdate DESC
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is simple using Mysql Limit, you can use "LIMIT 5", in your case your code will be like

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total FROM table 
WHERE DAY(date) = DAY('2016-01-18') 
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH('2016-01-18') 
AND YEAR(date) = YEAR('2016-01-18') 
GROUP BY text ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5
```

it should return only top 5 results.